# APA citation - parenthethical with page number and textual

Tags: natbib, apa-style, apacite

I need my text as following.

It was raining (De Silva & Lee, 2018). There was a cat (Kahouli & Maktouf, 2015, p. 12). Baier,
Yotov, and Zylkin (2019) said that the cat was running.

First, the versions like \citep etc not working. Secondly I got the title of article to all lower case in the bibliography. Moreover, I would like to make the in text citations in blue font and hyperlinked. A lot of guidance available online on this topic but that is confusing or works only partially.

Any help please!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage {apacite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\title {\textbf {This is an interesting title of the article}}
\author[1]{Firstname Lastname}
\affil[1]{ABC University, City, Country}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}
It was raining \cite{de2018does}. There was a cat \cite{kahouli2015trade}. \cite{baier2019widely} said that the cat was running.

\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

The reference in the separate Reference.bib file I put here.

```
@article{baier2019widely,
  title={On the widely differing effects of free trade agreements: Lessons from twenty years of trade integration},
  author={Baier, Scott L and Yotov, Yoto V and Zylkin, Thomas},
  journal={Journal of International Economics},
  volume={116},
  pages={206--226},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{de2018does,
  title={Does the role of observer countries in the regional trade agreement matter for intra-regional trade?},
  author={De Silva, Dakshina G and Lee, Soon-Cheul},
  journal={Applied Economics},
  volume={50},
  number={20},
  pages={2219--2228},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{kahouli2015trade,
  title={Trade creation and diversion effects in the Mediterranean area: Econometric analysis by gravity model},
  author={Kahouli, Bassem and Maktouf, Samir},
  journal={The Journal of International Trade \& Economic Development},
  volume={24},
  number={1},
  pages={76--104},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

Comment: If you want to use the `\citep` and other `natbib` citation commands, you need to load `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option. Lowercasing of titles is what the APA format requires, so this is not a bug. For hyperlinks, you need to load the `hyperref` package *before* you load `apacite`. Since `hyperref` generally likes to be loaded last, you should therefore load `hyperref` second last and `apacite` as the very last package loaded in your preamble.

Comment: Thank @AlanMunn 
- apacite with natbibapa option worked well.
- hyperref also worked. I got that the sequence of the uploading packages matters in certain situation. Thanks!
- To keep certain words in the uppercase, I used {} around them as I found this in some other conversations.

Answer (score 1):

I will share my setup for working with APA style references. I do not know if it will answer all your concerns.

1. To keep capital letters in titles, you must enclose them in (double) braces
   {}. See Referencesx.bib
2. I found the `biblatex` and `biber` combination much more convenient
   and easier to work with.
3. Use \citep.
4. It is strongly recommended to load `hyperref` as the last package.
   It is highly configurable. I don't know if my setup is what you
   wanted, but it will put you on the right track.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage {apacite} %not used
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15}

\title {\textbf {This is an interesting title of the article}}
\author[1]{Firstname Lastname}
\affil[1]{ABC University, City, Country}


%%*****************  ADDED
\usepackage[style=apa,
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
language=american]
{biblatex}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% format hyperlinks
\colorlet{linkcolour}{blue}  %blue
\colorlet{urlcolour}{blue}

\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=3,   
    colorlinks, 
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=linkcolour,
    citecolor=linkcolour,
    urlcolor=urlcolour, 
    filecolor=black,
    linktocpage=true, 
} % Set up hyperlinks including colors for references, urls and citations

\addbibresource{Referencesx.bib}

%% **********************************************************************

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}
It was raining \citep{de2018does}. There was a cat \citep{kahouli2015trade}. \citep{baier2019widely} said that the cat was running.

%\bibliography{References}

\newpage

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Titles in double braces.
**Update**  To avoid incompatibilities that may arise with other styles, it is advisable to use the `{ }` only in words or letters, not the full titles, as in

title = {{NASA} sends {MarsProve} to search for {L}a, {A}c, {T}h {P}a and {U} actinides to the {K}uiper belt},

File: Referencesx.bib

```
@article{baier2019widely,
  title={{On the widely differing effects of free trade agreements: Lessons from twenty years of trade integration}},
  author={Baier, Scott L and Yotov, Yoto V and Zylkin, Thomas},
  journal={Journal of International Economics},
  volume={116},
  pages={206--226},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{de2018does,
  title={Does the role of observer countries in the regional trade agreement matter for intra-regional trade?},
  author={De Silva, Dakshina G and Lee, Soon-Cheul},
  journal={Applied Economics},
  volume={50},
  number={20},
  pages={2219--2228},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{kahouli2015trade,
  title={{Trade creation and diversion effects in the Mediterranean area: Econometric analysis by gravity model}},
  author={Kahouli, Bassem and Maktouf, Samir},
  journal={The Journal of International Trade \& Economic Development},
  volume={24},
  number={1},
  pages={76--104},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}
```

[image: first]

[image: second]

Comment: I'm sorry but this is *not* the way to deal with capitalization. The APA style requires sentence case for titles, and if that's not the style you want, you shouldn't be using one of the 'official' APA styles (`apacite` or `biblatex-apa`), but instead should use a more generic author year style. You should never (need to) make adjustments to your `.bib` file to adapt to a style. The `.bib` file should be style neutral, and all formatting done by `biblatex`.  And this does *not* implement APA style anymore, since it will the title casing wrong if you have a `.bib` entry with Title Case.

Comment: To preserve the case of particular *words* in your `.bib` file, just enclose those words (not the whole title) in `{...}`.

Comment: Thanks @SimonDispa
As I mentioned in my commented I just posted above, the `apacite` worked with the `natbibapa` option. But I will try the `biblatex` and `biber` combination just to have more understanding.
About preserving the case, I read some other ways in some conversations, yet the simplest one is using the `{}` as you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @Alan Munn   Just to clarify: from APA 7ed section 6.17 

https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/capitalization/title-case

APA Style uses two types of capitalization for titles of works (such as paper titles) and headings within works: title case and sentence case.

In title case, major words are capitalized, and most minor words are lowercase.
Major words: Nouns, verbs (including linking verbs), adjectives, adverbs, pronouns, and all words of four letters or more are considered major words.

Comment: @SimonDispa This may have changed from v6 to v7, but is irrelevant to the point I'm making. You should not fix capitalization problems by putting whole titles in `{...}`. Ideally your `.bib` entries should be in title case, and words that must *always* be capitalized independent of style should be in `{...}`, not the whole title.

Comment: @Amos Machado This the  way I  deal with the 1993 paper of Greenwade in TUGBoat

 title   = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},

Comment: @Alan Munn  I updated my answer with your warning.

Comment: @SimonDispa Why not actually fix the example `.bib` too. It's not a warning. You should simply not do what you've done to your `.bib` file examples here. It's bad practice.